# Can a NuGet package edit source files in the project it is installed into?

Tags: c#, nuget

Here's the scenario. I'd like to package a `SettingsProvider` into a NuGet package. Using the provider requires adding an attribute to the project's `Settings` class in `Settings.cs`. It would look like this:

```cs
    [SettingsProvider(typeof(MyNugetSettingsProvider))]
    public sealed partial class Settings
        {
        // contents elided for clarity
        }
```

Normally, that attribute isn't there by default, but I'd like the NuGet package to add it automatically, or at least add a comment with a ToDo item in it.

One solution is to include the Settings.cs file in the NuGet package, but I don't want to simply overwrite any existing file because it may already contain user code. Creating the file if it is missing would be OK, but if it's already there, then I'd like to just insert the attribute on the class.

So, is there a supported/recommended way of doing that sort of thing?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/source-and-config-file-transformations#specifying-source-code-transformations

Comment: Personally, I'd hate to see a Nuget package modifying my source code, but each to their own!

Comment: It is a terrible idea to modify code, and right now "generators" isn't implemented (I keep asking them, and they keep deferring); however, there *are* ways to generate code files into the build, and since you're using a `partial class`, you can generate a **separate** file that has nothing but the namespace, partial class and attribute... but: it is a **lot** of work to do this, especially if you need to parse code (presumably via Roslyn) to even do it... you'd need to *really, really* be invested for this.

Comment: On the other hand: a code analyzer with a suggestion feature (like other code-fixes in the IDE): that's actually much much easier! i.e. your analyzer detects that it is missing, warns the user visibly, and provides a one-click fix that adds the attribute.

Comment: @MarcGravell oooh yes, I like the idea of using an analyzer. No need to modify the code, just let the user do it. Now all I need is to learn to write analyzers ;-)

Comment: @DavidG I tend to agree

Comment: @TimLong and importantly: analyzers can be shipped as nuget packages